# Unable to figure out 504 error in NodeJS running on NGINX Web Server on AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, post, request

When I'm making POST requests to 3rd party APIs like Facebook, Google etc in a sequence, I'm getting 504 error randomly. I'm unable to pinpoint an exact scenario that is causing the error.

Here is how I'm making the POST request:

```
 var options = { uri: uri,
                 headers: {
                   "Content-Type": "application/json",
                 },
                 strictSSL: true,
                 json: obj
               }; 


 request.post(options, function(err, response) {


 });
```

Here is my NGINX config file:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
 worker_connections  1024;
}


http {

  client_max_body_size 100M;
  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;

  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

  sendfile        on;


  keepalive_timeout  65;

  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;


}
```

I'm running my app on 2 EC2 Instances in AWS with a load balancer attached to it.

What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're missing a server block inside the http block. And it wouldn't hurt to have location blocks to redirect the client to more finely tuned routes rather than just the root

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  root /home/ubuntu/public_html;

  server_name example-one.com www.example-one.com;

  location /application1 {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/sampleApp;
  }

  location /images {
      root /home/ubuntu/data;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have the server block inside the config file in `sites-enabled` folder.